# Keep getting Unicode Error with Streamlit

Tags: python, python-3.x, streamlit

I am trying to use OpenAi and Streamlit together to merge them into a little dummy website. Here is the coding:

```
save_folder = "files"
if not os.path.exists(save_folder):
    os.makedirs(save_folder)

uploaded_files = st.file_uploader("Choose a file", accept_multiple_files=True)
for uploaded_file in uploaded_files:
    bytes_data = uploaded_file.read()
    s = bytes_data.decode("UTF-8")
    
    with open(f"{save_folder}/{uploaded_file.name}", "w") as f:
        f.write(s)

SimpleDirectoryReader = download_loader("SimpleDirectoryReader")
loader = SimpleDirectoryReader(save_folder)
documents = loader.load_data()


index = GPTSimpleVectorIndex(documents)
index.save_to_disk('index.json')
question = st.text_input("What do you want me to do with the file uploaded?")
response = index.query(question)
st.write(response)
```

I keep getting the same error:

```
  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 565, in _run_script

    exec(code, module.__dict__)

  File "/app/indextest/streamlit_app.py", line 17, in <module>

    s = bytes_data.decode("UTF-8")

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 14-15: invalid continuation byte
```

Anyone know why?

Comment: What type of file are you uploading when you're seeing that error?